# How store foreach value in laravel with checkbox

Tags: php, laravel

I have view code that get values from loop and each value have a checkbox

```
@foreach($materials as $material)

    <div class="card card-pricing bg-gradient-success border-0 text-center mb-4 mr-3 mx-auto col-lg-4">
        <a href="#" id="{{$material->price}}">
            <div class="card-header bg-transparent">
                <h4 class="text-uppercase ls-1 text-white py-3 mb-0">{{$material->name}}</h4>
                <img src="/zoby/uploads/materials/{{$material->image}}" height="100" class="rounded-circle">
            </div>

            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="display-4 text-white mb-2">{{$material->price}} زومن </div>
                <span class=" text-white"> در ازای هر {{$material->unit}}</span>
            </div>

            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
                <input class="custom-control-input" id="{{$material->id}}" type="checkbox" name="material" value="{{$material->id}}">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{$material->id}}">{{$material->name}} دارم </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
@endforeach
```

I want when one or some items checked in my controller for each request execute a db insert command.

what i must write in my controller?

```
    public function requests_new_post(Request $request)
{

    foreach ($request->material as $material) {

        DB::table('materials')->insert([

            ?????

        ]);
    }


    return redirect('/panel/addresses');
}
```

Comment: _Side note:_ The two last `</div>` and `</a>` should swap places.

Comment: show us the model of materials. And the column where you want to save those checboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change,

```
name="material"
```

To,

```
name="material[]"
```

This will allow you to pass an array of values.

Then in your controller when the form is submitted, you'd loop through the array of passed data:

```
foreach ($request->material as $material) {
     // $material will not contain the value of the submitted checkbox
    //  Run your query in here
}
```